# Random error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_Loader

Tags: php, zend-framework, backbone.js

I have multiple Zend applications across a few virtual hosts. E.G. intranet.site.com and api.site.com. I am having some trouble accessing api.site.com *sometimes*. I also have multiple backbone.js models which make requests to the API to fill the models.

When I load an intranet page, it will successfully do an XHR to the API at least 1 out of 3 times. The other times, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_Loader in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\Loader.php on line 31

Now, it happens sporadically. I sometimes get it when it's just a normal GET request (i.e. not an XMLHTTPRequest), but I mostly get it when I do more than one API request on a single page load.

It's as though it's not treating the other API calls as a separate request? I'm not sure what could cause it, seeing as it works sporadically.

I'm on a Windows 7 environment with XAMPP if that matters. It appears to have fewer issues on a linux environment, but I can't develop the system on a linux environment...

Comment: try doing KeepAlive off in your apache config file.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work :( my connection says 'close' now instead of 'keep-alive' but yeah, didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may:

- be using Superluminal plugin and try to require_once the Loader.php
- have some kind of class cache, that loads more files at once - and then any require_once call to any the included classes fails
- have a problem with APC/ZendOptimizer/etc. that caches classes